# Accept GZIP-encoded request body as-is in Firebase Functions

Tags: node.js, express, http, google-cloud-functions, gzip

In a Firebase Function, I'm trying to accept a large string and store it.

```
exports.store = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    const body : string = req.body;
    await store(body);
    return req.send(...);
});
```

I have found that using GZIP can improve performance and reduce file size by about 3-4x.

The problem is that if a client sends a GZip-encoded string with content encoding like so:

```
header("Content-Encoding", "gzip")
```

Then the call to `req.body` will 'automagically' decode the string to UTF-8. This both drastically reduces performance and requires me to *again* compress the string to efficiently store it in the server.

If I don't specify a content encoding then the endpoint will work as expected (i.e. it won't decompress the string and store it as-is, and run faster as a result). The problem is then I can't verify the user has sent a gzip-compressed string instead of a UTF-8 one, unless I implement some hacks to check for patterns in the string.

I am sure there is some simple solution, e.g.

```
functions.dontInflateTheRequestPleaseThanks();
exports.store = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    if (req.headers["content-encoding"] !== "gzip") return res.status(415).send("gzip please");
    const body : string = req.body;
    await store(body);
    return req.send(...);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to not pass `Content-Encoding=gzip` so express (the underlying framework) won't inflate (decompress) the request. Then to identify the request as a gzip, pass `ContentType=application/gzip`.

```
    if (req.headers["content-encoding"] === "gzip") {
        res.status(415).send("Don't specify gzip as the content-encoding. This trips up firebase.");
        return;
    }
    if (req.headers["content-type"] !== "application/gzip") {
        res.status(415).send("must be compressed using gzip");
        return;
    }
    // Then body is guaranteed to not be fiddled with.
    const body = req.body;
```

Answer (score -1):

You have some middleware which fills `req.body` already and auto-decompresses it along the way. Instead, you can collect the body yourself.

Caution: The middleware that already fills `req.body` uses the same `on("data")`/`on("end")` technique as the code below, therefore you must make sure that this code is *not* executed together with the body-filling middleware.

To ensure this, pass an entire express app to `functions.https.onRequest`:

```js
exports.store = functions.https.onRequest(express().use(async (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.headers["content-encoding"] !== "gzip")
    return res.status(415).send("gzip please");
  var buffers = [];
  req.on("data", function(data) {
    buffers.push(data);
  }).on("end", async function() {
    await store(Buffer.concat(buffers));
    res.send(...);
  });
}));
```

Comment: The bodies of `on("data")` and `on("end")` never get called, hanging the function, server, and emulator.

Comment: @FudgeFudge, I simplified it too much. Have edited my answer and included a word of caution.

Comment: How do i disable the middleware? Is it even possible in firebase?

Comment: Try passing an entire express app to `functions.https.onRequest`, as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#using_existing_express_apps).